# -bash: ssh-i: command not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, macos, ssh, mautic

I am trying to login into my EC2 instance through my terminal(MAC) but once I run the command ssh -i 'pem file path' bitnami@ip-address I am getting this error **-bash: ssh-i: command not found**

Comment: you need to have spaces between the command the option, this is what error saying.use something like <ssh [spaces] -i  [spaces]  key.pem [spaces]  bitnami@ip-address>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you missed a space between `ssh` and `-i`.

```sh
ssh -i path/to/identity.file bitnami@ip-address
```

Answer (score -1):

run this command **brew install openssh** in the terminal and try to login it will work

Comment: but MacOS has this command builtin ??? why do you have to install it.

Comment: Macos comes with a perfectly fine copy of `ssh`. You can install another copy of ssh if you want. But it's unlikely that this was the source of your problem or the way to fix it.